# How should I build two svelte pages with rollup?

Tags: svelte

I'm following the official [Svelte for new developers](https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-for-new-developers) blog post for my svelte app. It's working fine, and now I want to add a separate "admin" app. Except for interfacing the same database and being hosted on the same domain, it shares no components with my main app.

Would the best approach be to create a second svelte app and host it in a folder, or is there a way do to this in the same rollup?

```
npx degit sveltejs/template my-project-admin-page
```

Comment: created this hiring a friend of mine: github.com/kokizzu/svelte-mpa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `rollup.config.js` can return a an array instead, so you would get something like

```js
export default [
  { ...config for normal app ...},
  { ...config for admin app ...}
]
```

I like to abstract some of the more common parts as well, in a project I am currently working on I have:

```js
export default [
    getConfig('index'),
    getConfig('admin')
]
```

You could add extra parameters, the one here just points to the main entry point and uses the same name for the bundle

Comment: Thanks for answer, can you explain more details please?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using [svelte-kit](https://kit.svelte.dev/), but for simplicity reasons, once I used [tinro](https://github.com/AlexxNB/tinro) and it was so good and simple, you can also use [svelte-routing](https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing).

In this case, your code will be like:

```html
<Route path="/">
  <a href="/admin">Go to admin</a>
  <h2>You are on main page</h2>
</Route>
<Route path="/admin">
  <a href="/">Back to tasks</a>
  <h2>You are on admin page</h2>
</Route>
```

tinro: https://github.com/AlexxNB/tinro

tinro-example: https://svelte.dev/repl/4bc37ff40ada4111b71fe292a4eb90f6?version=3.46.4

svelte-routing: https://github.com/EmilTholin/svelte-routing

Answer (score 0):

Just for sake of completeness, I use this one [Svelte-MPA](https://github.com/kokizzu/svelte-mpa)

You can just create a .svelte file (page) and it would generate .html on build/watch, for any other .svelte file that started with underscore or in folder that starts with underscore it would became a svelte component that can be imported by other svelte page.